# Creating a DFA that only accepts number of a's that are multiples of 3

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I am brand new to DFA's and my first exercise requires me to create a DFA instance such that the number of a's in the string is a multiple of 3. We only have two types of symbols: a, b. To my understanding something like "aaabbaaa" would work but "aabbb" would not. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Can you formulate a grammar or regular expression for that language? What would you do if there were no $b$? What would you do if it were multiples of two?

Comment: You can find an answer [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7879/algorithms-computing-if-a-number-is-a-multiple-of-3/7889#7889), I guess this question would count as a duplicate.

Comment: @john_leo [That question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7879/algorithms-computing-if-a-number-is-a-multiple-of-3) is about telling whether an integer is a multiple of 3 from its binary representation. This problem has nothing to do with the question here, which is about telling whether the number of occurrences of a letter in a string is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Hm, OK, sorry. But it does also say $3$ here.

Comment: Describe in your own words what the further input has to be if the first symbol is b. Or if it is a.

Answer (score 3):

The key idea here is to make a ring of three states, $q_0, q_1, q_2$ with $a$ transitions 
$$\begin{align}
q_0 & \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow}q_1\\
q_1 & \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow}q_2\\
q_2 & \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow}q_0
\end{align}$$
On input $aaa$, for example, you'll start in state $q_0$ and pass to state $q_1$ on the first $a$, $q_2$ on the second, and back to $q_0$ on the third $a$. Clearly, any multiple of three $a$s will leave you in state $q_0$, so we make that a final state.

What to do about $b$s in the input? They don't have any effect on the number of $a$s, so include transitions 
$$\begin{align}
q_0 & \stackrel{b}{\rightarrow}q_0\\
q_1 & \stackrel{b}{\rightarrow}q_1\\
q_2 & \stackrel{b}{\rightarrow}q_2
\end{align}$$
and you're done. In fancier terms, we're $q_n$ to "remember" whether the number of $a$s seen so far was congruent to $n\pmod{3}$. This idiom, using the states to remember certain situations, is fundamental when designing FAs.

Answer (score 1):

We need that the number of $a$'s will be only multiple of $3$, e.g words like
$aaa,baaab,bababa,bbbbaaaaaa,\dots$  ets, so we will put the accept state on place such that the number of $a$'s $\mod(3)=0$ e.g $0\mod(3)=0,3\mod(3)=0,6\mod(3)=0,\dots$

Try this DFA:[image]